# Is there a way to populate values in a Hashmap to remove specific values in a text file?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I am new to using Hashmaps and curious to know how to use a single key for multiple values  and remove those specific values from the output .

```
public static class initiateParsing extends DoFn<Msg, ArrayList<String>> {
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        Msg msg = c.element();
        String line = msg.getLine();

        Map<String, String> attributes = msg.getAttributes();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


        attributes.put("#", "Software");
        attributes.put("#", "Remark");
        attributes.put("#", "Date");
        attributes.put("#", "Start-Date");
        attributes.put("#", "Fields");

        try {

            Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^\\s\"]+|\"[^\"]*\"");
            Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(line);
            while (regexMatcher.find()) {
                String match = regexMatcher.group();
                match = removeLeadingChar(match, "\"");
                match = removeLeadingChar(match, "\'");
                list.add(match);
            }
```

Comment: `HashMap` is a hash table implementation based on Java’s `Map` interface. A Map, as you might know, is a collection of key-value pairs. It maps keys to values.  `HashMap has few key points to note: *i)* A `HashMap` **cannot contain duplicate keys**. *ii)* `HashMap` allows null values and the null key. *iii)* `HashMap` is an unordered collection. It does not guarantee any specific order of the elements. and *iv)* `HashMap` is not thread-safe. You must explicitly synchronize concurrent modifications to the `HashMap`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Always be specific and make your best effort before asking, and don't treat Stack Overflow as a repository of tutorials. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions. I recommend you first search on Google about `HashMap` and the edit your question.

Comment: You will need to do Map<String, List<String>>. It's tricky though.

Comment: @Teocci Ok thank you I will revise my question

Comment: @Sedrick What do you mean ? should I put all the Strings  into the  list array then proceed?

Comment: I don't really know what you need. But if you need a Map that can map many values to one key then what I suggested will work.

Comment: @Sedrick well ultimately I will need the map to gather many values  under the same key then later on in the code  remove  the specific  values.

Comment: @Xfactor, you have defined `DoFn<Msg, ArrayList<String>>` this means, your keys are Msg objects and your values are ArrayList<String> objects. So  I don't know what does `msg.getAttributes()` method add the `Msg` class also to you question

Comment: “how to use a single key for multiple values and remove those specific values from the output” —What key?  What output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ArrayList in a HashMap i suppose.

```
Map<String,ArrayList<String>> attributes = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<String> vaules= new ArrayList<String>();

values.add("Software");
values.add("Remark");
values.add("Date");
values.add("Start-Date");
values.add("Fields");

attributes.put("#", values);
```

Comment: Thanks for Your reponse but then how would I remove those specific values I have added?

Comment: @Xfactor Do you want to remove all the values under the key '#' or only some of them. What kind of a output you are talking about?